# How to stop Jetty webserver in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty

If you are doing local development I want to know how we can stop/kill Jetty webserver? I have to close my Eclipse IDE whenever I need to do that. Is there any other way to do it? Or we have to kill the process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see Jetty instance(s) running in one of the `Console`. Just press the <kbd>Red Button</kbd>.

Comment: I got you. That red button did not appear every time. If I have to stop it from red button. I have attempt to debug/run again. And in the middle of process. I press the red button.

Comment: Does that mean that my answer satisfies your request?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty can be stopped in the following ways:

- You can click the "red" button in the Eclipse console window
- You can type "q" then hit enter in the console window (or "r" for restart) (This may only work for Run Jetty Run)

If both of those fail, then if you're on linux or osx, you can open a terminal window and type the following to find the process id of Jetty and kill it. The process id is the 2nd column shown in the results, and you'll need to be careful that you're not seeing some other process here as well:

```
ps aux | grep jetty | grep java
```

then run the following to kill the process

```
kill process_id_from_above_call
```

You can run the above 2 commands in one shot by doing this:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep jetty | grep java | awk '{print $2}')
```

but be *sure* you're matching Jetty before you do this, as you may kill something you don't want to kill if it doesn't match correctly ;-) Note that if it still isn't killed by the above, you can force it to be killed by doing this:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep jetty | grep java | awk '{print $2}')
```